# Joomla Directory Permissions

Tags: linux, joomla2.5, fedora

Hello i have problem with joomla directory premissions. Am using Fedora 19 KDE. I success install joomla and i start to develop my own component. When i start install component i get this error:
**Warning: Failed to move file!**

Ok what i do next. I check premissions in **system information > directory premissions** and all there is  **Unwritable**.

What i do next. first i check owner:

```
cd /var/www/html

[ikac@localhost html]$ ls -l

drwxrwxrwx+ 17 ikac apache 4096 Aug 15 15:07 joomla-2.5
```

Again unwritable:

I try

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache joomla-2.5
```

And try this

```
sudo chmod -R 777 joomla-2.5/tmp
sudo chmod -R 777 joomla-2.5/component
sudo chmod -R 777 joomla-2.5/administrator
```

Nothing again unwritable. I try to put chmod **775** but nothing.

Any other solution how to make writable directories. I dont have more idea. I change owner, mode, and more else.

Here is full dir premission:

```
[ikac@localhost joomla-2.5]$ ls -l
total 204
drwxrwxrwx+ 10 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 administrator
drwxrwxrwx+  2 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 cache
drwxrwxrwx+  2 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 cli
drwxrwxrwx+ 13 ikac ikac  4096 Aug 15 17:01 components
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  1807 Aug 15 15:07 configuration.php
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  3118 Aug  1 04:01 htaccess.txt
drwxrwxrwx+  4 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 images
drwxrwxrwx+  2 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 includes
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  1319 Aug  1 04:01 index.php
drwxrwxrwx+ 10 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 installation1
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  1752 Aug  1 04:04 joomla.xml
drwxrwxrwx+  4 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 language
drwxrwxrwx+  7 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 libraries
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac 17816 Aug  1 04:01 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxrwx+  2 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 logs
drwxrwxrwx+ 15 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 media
drwxrwxrwx+ 26 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 modules
drwxrwxrwx+ 13 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 plugins
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  4244 Aug  1 04:01 README.txt
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac   865 Aug  1 04:01 robots.txt.dist
drwxrwxrwx+  6 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 templates
drwxrwxrwx+  2 ikac ikac  4096 Aug  1 04:01 tmp
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 ikac ikac  1715 Aug  1 04:01 web.config.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Problem be on fedora. SELinux block all premission. I disable SElinux and all is writable. That is be problem.

Comment: Since you found your answer, put it in as an answer and select it as the correct one in case someone else has the same problem.